# JAVA - the smallest base

Tags: java, radix

Hey guys have another question, just wondering what is a good method to use to find the "Smallest Possible Base". So working off:

Say if I have the number 10121, the base would be 3. But I have no idea how to achieve these in Java, can I get any tips to a good method to get this return value. If more information is needed I'll post the question if I'm not making sense. Thanks

Edit:
Wow, so many downvotes, I'm asking for an explanation for how to get the bases in Java, thus why I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: Post an attempt at a solution

Comment: can you show your code.

Comment: guys, that's a perfectly valid question. It could be more clear, but still, it is a good question. Why the downvotes? It doesn't make much sense to post code that doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would probably do - note that it will not give you correct results for base 64 numbers.

```
public static int getSmallestPossibleBase(String value) {
    int max = 0;
    for (char c : value.toCharArray()) {
        int type = Character.getType(c);
        switch (type) {
            case Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER:
                // Decimal digit.
                max = Math.max(max, c - '0');
                break;
            case Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER:
            case Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER:
                // Works for base 16 and 32/36.
                max = Math.max(max, Character.toLowerCase(c) - 'a' + 10);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your argument is invalid");
        }
    }
    return max + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the "base = Math.max(base, c - '0');" is what I mainly needed for my code to work.

Comment: @AlexJack - I've made it a little better.

Answer (score 2):

Java [uses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)) these characters as digits for numbers in bases 2 through 36:

```
String digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

You task is to go through `String value` character-by-character, and find the position of that lowercased character in the string of digits. If the character is not there in `digits`, the value cannot be converted to a number. Otherwise, the character would be at the position `pos`. Find the highest such `pos`, and return `maxPos+1` as your answer.

For example, for `val = "DeadBeef"` you should get the position of character `'f'`, i.e. 15. Adding one to it gives you 16, meaning that `val` is a valid hexadecimal number.

Comment: And then there's Base64 :(

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I'm curious what you think would be a problem with expanding `digits` to cover Base64?

Comment: Because Base64 has `A = 0`, `B = 1`, ... `a = 26` etc.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Removing `toLowerCase` and appending `A..Z` to the back of `digits` string should solve this problem, right? Of course `DeadBeef` would have a different base of 40.

Answer (score 1):

The base-x number would have all digits less than `x`.

So your aim would be to get the highest digit and return `+1` to it to get the least possible base.

In this case

```
101211
```

The highest digit is `2`, and hence the least base is `3`.

```
char ch = '0';
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
 {
   char c = str.charAt(i);
   if(c > ch)
    ch = c;
 }
System.out.println(c - '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through the single digits.

Find the biggest one.

The smallest base is 1 + biggest digit.

For example for the string `1232332234212` the max digit is **4** so the minimum base is **5**

For the string `101000010001010001` the max digit is **1** so the minimum base is **2**.

If you need to handle also letters convert a letter to a number A = 10, B = 11 and so on. And apply the same algorithm